# How to merge two C# Lambda Expressions without an invoke?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, lambda

I'd like to merge the following Expressions:

```
// example class
class Order
{
    List<OrderLine> Lines       
}
class OrderLine { }

Expression<Func<Order, List<OrderLine>>> selectOrderLines = o => o.Lines;
Expression<Func<List<OrderLine>, Boolean>> validateOrderLines = lines => lines.Count > 0;

// now combine those to
Expression<Func<Order, Boolean>> validateOrder;
```

I got it to work using a invoke on the selectOrderLines and supplying the result to the validateOrderLines, but because I'm using these expressions in Entity Framework, I have to actually create a clean expression which should represent:

```
Expression<Func<Order, Boolean>> validateOrder = o => o.Lines.Count > 0;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The most elegant way is to use an [Expression Visitor](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2007/11/04/linq-expression-visitor/). In particular, this [MSDN Blog Entry](http://web.archive.org/web/20090422054328/http://blogs.msdn.com/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx) describes how to use it to combine predicates (using boolean And or Or) without Invoke.

**EDITED** Having realized boolean combination is not what you wanted, I wrote a sample usage of ExpressionVisitor that solves for your particular problem:

```
public class ParameterToMemberExpressionRebinder : ExpressionVisitor
{
    ParameterExpression _paramExpr;
    MemberExpression _memberExpr;

    ParameterToMemberExpressionRebinder(ParameterExpression paramExpr, MemberExpression memberExpr) 
    {
        _paramExpr = paramExpr;
        _memberExpr = memberExpr;
    }

    protected override Expression Visit(Expression p)
    {
        return base.Visit(p == _paramExpr ? _memberExpr : p);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CombinePropertySelectorWithPredicate<T, T2>(
        Expression<Func<T, T2>> propertySelector,
        Expression<Func<T2, bool>> propertyPredicate)
    {
        var memberExpression = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("propertySelector");
        }

        var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(propertyPredicate.Body, propertySelector.Parameters);
        var rebinder = new ParameterToMemberExpressionRebinder(propertyPredicate.Parameters[0], memberExpression);
        expr = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)rebinder.Visit(expr);

        return expr;
    }

    class OrderLine
    {
    }

    class Order
    {
        public List<OrderLine> Lines;
    }

    static void test()
    {
        Expression<Func<Order, List<OrderLine>>> selectOrderLines = o => o.Lines;
        Expression<Func<List<OrderLine>, Boolean>> validateOrderLines = lines => lines.Count > 0;
        var validateOrder = ParameterToMemberExpressionRebinder.CombinePropertySelectorWithPredicate(selectOrderLines, validateOrderLines);

        // validateOrder: {o => (o.Lines.Count > 0)}
    }
}
```

Comment: Ben any change you are still at this? I need to do some special merging you might want to help me with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55440167/how-to-merge-object-expressions?noredirect=1#comment97597118_55440167 was trying to change yours to my need https://github.com/sturlath/CombineObjectExpressionsTest/blob/6cbff056b0a6e4e3d7cce90af8c0d723a8a82125/CombineObjectExpressions/Extensions/ParameterToMemberExpressionRebinder.cs#L7 without luck

Answer (score 3):

This extension works:

```
public static class Utility
    {
        public static Expression<T> Compose<T>(this Expression<T> first, Expression<T> second, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> merge)
        {
            // build parameter map (from parameters of second to parameters of first)
            var map = first.Parameters.Select((f, i) => new { f, s = second.Parameters[i] }).ToDictionary(p => p.s, p => p.f);

            // replace parameters in the second lambda expression with parameters from the first
            var secondBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(map, second.Body);

            // apply composition of lambda expression bodies to parameters from the first expression 
            return Expression.Lambda<T>(merge(first.Body, secondBody), first.Parameters);
        }

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
        {
            return first.Compose(second, Expression.And);
        }

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
        {
            return first.Compose(second, Expression.Or);
        }
    }
```

Sample using:

```
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> filter1 = p => a.ProductId == 1;
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> filter2 = p => a.Text.StartWith("test");
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> filterCombined = filter1.And(filter2);
```

Comment: What Would I need to to in order to add brackets to this ?
I mean If I want to build a filter like 
(ProductId ==1 or ProductId ==2) and a.text.StartsWith("a")

Comment: Where do i find the parameterRebinder?

Comment: If for some reason you're still looking for parameterRebinder, it can be found at [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx)