# Linq expression subsonic 3.0.0.3

Tags: linq, subsonic, subsonic3, expression

I want to 'build' a combined query for Subsonic 3.0.0.3, what is the best way for this?

I tried;

```
        Expression<Func<Person, bool>> exp = p => true;
        Expression<Func<Person, bool>> fContinent = p => p.ContinentID == 1;
        Expression<Func<Person, bool>> fType = p => p.TypeID == 1;
        exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(exp, fContinent), exp.Parameters);
        exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(exp, fType), exp.Parameters);
        var personList = Person.Find(exp);
```

But that will give the exception "The binary operator AndAlso is not defined ..."

I also tried using predicates but that will throw exceptions as well (Expression.Invoke is not supported).

In subsonic 2 I would have used the SqlQuery object, but I would like to know the proper way to do this in version 3 using linq / expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `And` instead of `AndAlso`?

The right way to do this is to combine the lambda expression *bodies*, like this:

```
exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(
    Expression.And(exp.Body, fContinent.Body), exp.Parameters);
```

Even if `And` is supported by your query provider, you'll also need to replace the parameter references in `fContinent`'s Body with references to the parameter defined in `exp`--as is, your two expression bodies (combined with `And`) reference two distinct parameters, each named `p`.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131869/) for the cleanest method to replace expression parameters.

Comment: I now understand it by reading the link you placed in your other post; http://blogs.msdn.com/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx

For my other question; is this the recommended way to build queries or should I be using the SqlQuery class?

Comment: I've never used Subsonic, so I can't say what's better.

Answer (score 0):

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932542/how-to-dynamically-build-and-return-a-linq-predicate-based-on-user-input), but I am using the combined query in subsonic just like you.

In short, you want to use a [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to build up the query. When you want to execute it in your subsonic object (assuming ActiveRecord), use code like this:

```
var predicate = /* Build up predicate with PredicateBuilder */;
var recs = SubsonicClass.All().Where(predicate.Compile()).ToList();
```