# How to dynamically build and return a linq predicate based on user input

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Getting a bit stuck on this. Basically I have a method that I want to return a predicate expression that I can use as a Where condition. 
I think what I need to do is similar to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx but I'm a bit stuck as to what I need to do.

Method:

```
private static Expression<Func<Conference, bool>> GetSearchPredicate(string keyword, int? venueId, string month, int year)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
    {
        // Want the equivilent of .Where(x => (x.Title.Contains(keyword) || x.Description.Contains(keyword)));
    }
    if (venueId.HasValue) 
    {
        // Some other predicate added...
    }

    return ??

}
```

Example Usage:

```
var predicate = GetSearchPreducate(a,b,c,d);
var x = Conferences.All().Where(predicate);
```

I need this separation so that I can pass my predicate into my repository and use it in other places.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you checked out [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: Nice, does exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 13):

A predicate is only a function that returns a boolean value.

I can not test it, right now, but wouldn't this work ?

```
private static Expression<Func<Conference, bool>> GetSearchPredicate(string keyword, int? venueId, string month, int year)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
    {
        //return a filtering fonction
        return (conf)=> conf.Title.Contains(keyword) || Description.Contains(keyword)));
    }
    if (venueId.HasValue) 
    {
        // Some other predicate added...
        return (conf)=> /*something boolean here */;
    }

    //no matching predicate, just return a predicate that is always true, to list everything
    return (conf) => true;

}
```

---

EDIT : based on Matt's comments
If you want to **compose the delegates**, you could proceed this way

```
private static Expression<Func<Conference, bool>> GetSearchPredicate(string keyword, int? venueId, string month, int year)
{   
    Expression<Func<Conference, bool> keywordPred = (conf) => true;
    Expression<Func<Conference, bool> venuePred = (conf) => true;
    //and so on ...


    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
    {
        //edit the filtering fonction
        keywordPred =  (conf)=> conf.Title.Contains(keyword) || Description.Contains(keyword)));
    }
    if (venueId.HasValue) 
    {
        // Some other predicate added...
        venuePred =  (conf)=> /*something boolean here */;
    }

    //return a new predicate based on a combination of those predicates
    //I group it all with AND, but another method could use OR
    return (conf) => (keywordPred(conf) && venuePred(conf) /* and do on ...*/);

}
```

Comment: Yeah, just like this. Just extract the (x=>something) part from where and save it into Expression<Func<Conference, bool>>.

Comment: Cheers, but I want to build upon the filter/predicate. So if a keyword is passed in, add the filter for that. And if a venueId also passed in, add the filter for that... That's where it all confuses me...

Comment: And when you use the expression where you need the predicate, use exp.Compile()

Comment: @Matt : ok then what you could do is build the Predicate piece by piece ... for instance, you could have a predicate for each of the fileds you check against and create a new predicate as the composition of all these ... I'll edit my answer ...

Comment: Thanks, that works but I found the predicatebuilder link to be a nicer solution so I'll go with that, I'll +1 you for a correct sln though.