# Combine OrderBy Expression with Where Expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression, linq-expressions

I found the following question that can combine multiple `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` expressions:

[How to merge two C# Lambda Expressions without an invoke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131869/how-to-merge-two-c-sharp-lamba-expressions-without-an-invoke)

I'm wondering whether, using a similar technique, how you go about merging a .OrderBy `Expression<Func<Entity, Key>>` with a .Where `Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>` into one Expression of type, or inheriting from type, `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`.

I'm making a really cut down QueryProvider-style class for taking `T => T == ...` Func's via public methods `.Where` and `.OrderBy`. This is with the intention that the expression this class builds gets passed to a QueryTranslator to create suitable SQL.

A QueryTranslator of this style, when called from a QueryProvider, typically takes one `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` as an argument which it then translates to SQL.

I can follow through and understand the question above for merging two `.Where` Funcs. The following blog post was particularly useful for this, and I traced through each of the examples:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx

This CodeProject article was also useful:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24255/Exploring-Lambda-Expression-in-C

When combining a .OrderBy Func with a .Where Func however the two have different generic arguments. In the case of the .Where it's a `Func<Entity, bool>`, and in the case of the .OrderBy it's a `Func<Entity, Key>`.

Merging these two Expressions, on the surface, isn't as straight forward as merging two with the same generic arguments.

The in-built Func-Expression-producing-engine (unsure of exact term) is able to combine a .Where Func with a .OrderBy Func. I'm curious about what goes on under the hood when these two expressions are merged to become one `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`.  Is it possible, and if so how would you go about combining an `Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>` with an `Expression<Func<Entity,Key>>` assuming the Entity is of the same type in each Expression?

Comment: How should the resulting expression look like?

Comment: It should be the same as a .Where(T=>T.Name=="Cooper").OrderBy(T=>T.DateOfBirth)

Comment: You merge `.Where(x => condition1).Where(x => condition2)` to `.Where(x => condition1 && condition)` but you cannot merge `.Where(x => condition).OrderBy(x => value)` in the same sense. So, again, how should the resulting expression look like? `queryable.Where(x => condition).OrderBy(x => value)` does not return an expression, it returns an `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Not sure why this question is voted up so much. As it stands it does not make sense, and it is under-defined.

Comment: Apologies. Question updated to improve clarity. The .Where and .OrderBy's here always relate to the Expression that gets created when calling a .Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>>) or a .OrderBy(Expression<Func<T, Key>). It's about combining the Expressions that are created after calling these methods.

Answer (score 3):

```
public IQueryable<T> ApplyExpressions<T, TKey>(
  Expression<Func<T, TKey>> sortBy,
  Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterBy,
  IQueryable<T> source)
{
  return source.Where(filterBy).OrderBy(sortBy);
}


IQueryable<Customer> query = ApplyExpressions<Customer, int>(
  c => c.Age,
  c => c.Name.StartsWith("B"),
  myDC.Customers)

Expression queryExpression = query.Expression;  //tada
```

Comment: I like the straight-forwardness but it's not quite what I'm after. I don't have a source available so there's nothing to query against in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think where this question got ambiguous is because it's kind of unanswerable.

I was trying to build one super-expression, like how the `IQueryable<>` expression builder works with `.Where` and `.OrderBy` expressions all in one expression.

Without a subject, however, my limited understanding of Expressions and Expression Trees seems to suggest it's not possible.

To combine a `.Where` expression with a `.OrderBy` expression into one Expression you need  `MethodCallExpression`'s to separate the two `LambdaExpression`s.

The `MethodCallExpression` needs a subject to call the Method on. This is where the `IQueryable<>` gets used.

I've altered my Query class to keep all the `LambdaExpression`'s separate, and these then get passed to the QueryTranslator separately. The QT merges the output SQL into the right places.

This is as opposed to an `IQueryable<>` QueryProvider that analyses one super-Expression and outputs SQL into the right places based on `MethodCallExpression`'s in the Expression.