# Passing multiple lambda expression to the function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have in my project one genericRepository with function like this:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

and this works fine in cases if I want to get elements filtered by only one object.
What in the case I need to chain 3-4 where clauses?
Is there any way to pass array of expressions if now what is the best way to make this thing work?

After reading your answers and comments I managed to make write this:

```
Expression<Func<Role, bool>> first = s => s.Id == 1;
Expression<Func<Role, bool>> second = s => s.RoleName != "null";
Expression<Func<Role, bool>> combined = Expression.Lambda<Func<Role, bool>>(Expression.And(first.Body, second.Body));
```

but this gives me

> Additional information: Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131869/how-to-merge-two-c-sharp-lamba-expressions-without-an-invoke

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047561/how-to-pass-an-array-of-orderby-expression-to-a-method

Comment: I fail to see how this method is actually making anything easier for you.  Why not just take your queryable and call `Where`/`OrderBy`/etc. on it directly?

Comment: Idea was that to make one function which will fit all views with filtering i use instead of coding x methods which are 90% same

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx%E2%80%8E) to build the expression from where you are calling this method.

Here's an example:

```
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }

  var products = productRepository.Get(predicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can combine your predicates

[Combining Predicates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx)

Comment: Please note that link-only answers are useless when the link breaks. Please always add a summary that highlights the points of interest to the OP.