# How to merge object expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

My question is How can I merge **object** expressions like this one?

```
Func<T, object>
```

I created [a test project](https://github.com/sturlath/CombineObjectExpressionsTest) on GitHub where I show what I have been trying.

I have a basic **boolian** expression combination like this [here](https://github.com/sturlath/CombineObjectExpressionsTest/blob/d1a6c389867bf985cc0ad59ecb1fcad2254cfbdb/ExpressionTests/BooleanExpression.cs#L23)  working

```
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> filter1 = p => p.Name == "John Doe";
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> filter2 = p => p.Address == "Address 123";

// Two boolean expressions combined
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> filterCombined = filter1.And(filter2);

// Works as expected
filterCombined.Body.ToString().ShouldBe("((p.Name == \"John Doe\") And (p.Address == \"Address 123\"))");
```

**BUT**
what I can't get working is to combine two **object** ones like [here](https://github.com/sturlath/CombineObjectExpressionsTest/blob/d1a6c389867bf985cc0ad59ecb1fcad2254cfbdb/ExpressionTests/BooleanExpression.cs#L38)

```
Expression<Func<Employee, object>> filter1 = p => p.Info;
Expression<Func<Employee, object>> filter2 = p => p.Profile;

// Trying to combine two object expressions fails
Expression<Func<Employee, object>> filterCombined = ParameterToMemberExpressionRebinder.CombinePropertySelectorWithPredicate(filter1, filter2);

filterCombined.Body.ToString().ShouldBe("((p => p.Info And p => p.Profile))"); //Something like this anyway...
```

I have tried all kinds of things like [vistor pattern](https://exceptionnotfound.net/visitor-the-daily-design-pattern/), [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) etc. but I´m missing something.

**My main reason for doing this all**

This information isn't strictly needed for this question but might give some somebody some extra insight and me some different answers.

I need this for Entity Framework Include [to load related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data?fbclid=IwAR0bWnQ_nHyVxVVAc8vE7JYZmaQJ34i52AS0etPCXGAaYNTy67yA6uWJZIE). But above that Automapper can't map the following so I'm trying to take all the params and combine them into one that Automapper can then handle.

```
public MyModelDTO GetById(int? id, params Expression<Func<MyModelDTO , object>>[] includeExpressions)
{
  // here Automapper (with Automapper.Extension.ExpressionMapping) 
  // fails to do the mapping so I´m trying to combine them into one
  Expression<Func<MyModel, object>> mappedExpression= MapToType<Expression<Func<MyModel, object>>>(includeExpressions);

   // call the repository with EF expression
   var myModel = MyRepoGetById(id,mappedExpression);
   ...map myModel back to dto
   return myMappedDtoModel;
}

// The repository method
public MyModel  MyRepoGetById(int id, params Expression<Func<MyModel, object>>[] includeExpressions)
{
        if (includeExpressions.Any())
        {
            IQueryable<T> set = includeExpressions
              .Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
                (dbContext.Set<T>(), (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

            return await set.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
        }

        return dbContext.Set<T>().Find(id);
}
```

that I want to use like this

```
var result  = await service.GetById(id,x => x.ClassProperty, x => x.AnotherClassProperty);
```

Comment: `"((p => p.Info And p => p.Profile))"` what does it even mean? Neither `p.Info` or `p.Profile` are booleans, so what does `And` stand for here?

Comment: yes neither Info or Profile are booleans. They are objects that I am trying to use in my now updated example. Its connected to Entity Framework and loading of related data. And since this is all going through RazorPage->ServiceLayer->Repository and I have generic stuff in place I need to do this mapping. It all works for just one Expression not more. The 'And' you can see that in the github code https://github.com/sturlath/CombineObjectExpressionsTest/blob/d1a6c389867bf985cc0ad59ecb1fcad2254cfbdb/CombineObjectExpressions/Extensions/ExpressionExtensions.cs#L28 ]

Comment: Let's step back a bit. `I'm trying to take all the params and combine them into one that Automapper can then handle` Have you tried writing by hand (without any fancy automatic merging stuff) an expression that fits your use-case and can be handled by Automapper? If so, can you show it to us? There's no point in trying to build something dynamically if it cannot exist to begin with

Comment: ProjectTo doesn't need any Include. It fetches everything in your DTO, but you can exclude things with ExplicitExpansion.

Comment: Kevin that all works fine. I updated my example though with 2 tests that really show my problem with mapping https://github.com/sturlath/CombineObjectExpressionsTest/blob/02338fa9ef5a81987ee57988acf403857f4ea8e0/ExpressionTests/BooleanExpression.cs#L50 where the implementation is here https://github.com/sturlath/CombineObjectExpressionsTest/blob/02338fa9ef5a81987ee57988acf403857f4ea8e0/CombineObjectExpressions/ExpressionMethods.cs#L34. The automapper error is there. I tried to find a solution to it without luck either so I went looking for a Expression combo

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu sorry I didn't spot your comment but I don't get it either :-) Any idea how to do this mapping like I'm trying?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you replace Map with ProjectTo, so no Includes are needed. Check [the docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html).